# Slow performance with nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a reasonably large text file (~16k lines) which I am looping over and for each line, checking if a client IP:Port, server IP:Port and keyword exist in the row, using two for loops and nested `if x in line` statements to check if the line contains the information I am looking for.

After I have identified a row that contains the values I am looking for, I update a sqlite DB. Initially, this took a considerable amount of time to execute due as I did not have SQL UPDATE statements wrapped in a manual transaction. After making this change, execution time improved significantly, however I'm still finding the code below taking a few minutes to complete and I feel that my horrible looping structure is the cause.

I would be very grateful if anyone had any performance tips to help speed up the code below:

```
c.execute("SELECT client_tuple, origin_tuple FROM connections")
# returns ~ 8k rows each with two items, clientIP:port and serverIP:port
tuples = c.fetchall()

with open('connection_details.txt', 'r') as f:
    c.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
    # for each line in ~16k lines
    for line in f:
        # for each row returned from sql query
        for tuple in tuples:
            # if the client tuple (IP:Port) is in the line
            if tuple[0] in line:
                # if the origin tuple (IP:Port) is in the line
                if tuple[1] in line:
                    # if 'foo' is in the line
                    if 'foo' in line:
                        # lookup some value and update SQL with the value found
                        bar_value = re.findall(r'(?<=bar\s).+?(?=\,)', line)
                        c.execute("UPDATE connections "
                                    " SET bar = ? "
                                   "WHERE client_tuple = ? AND origin_tuple = ?",
                                    (bar_value[0], tuple[0], tuple[1]))

    conn.commit()
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using `tuple` as a variable name, as it is a built-in function.

Comment: posting an example of how the lines look like and an example tuple from the `fetchall()` would help us help you considerably. + you might want to take a look into `any()`, `all()` and *sets* since they have very fast membership tests.

Comment: nested loops by defition are slow. Code tweaks will not get you very far with those. You need to fix your algorithm.

Comment: Another idea would be to create an SQL database from the text file and update the original table using `join`s and so on

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if 'foo' in line:` check should be before `for tuple in tuples:` iterator, so you would automatically skip lines for which processing is not necessary

Second small improvement - [compile regexp](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.compile) outside of loops and use compiled matcher.

Comment: Thank you! I've re-ordered the `if` statement and code execution time has halved due to the reduced number of lines which even enter the `for tuple in tuples` loop. I've also joined the two `if tup[x] in line` lines into one statement as per @James suggestion. I'll look into compiling the regexp next to squeeze a bit more performance out. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't tighten up your `for` loops because you need to iterate over all of the tuples for each line in your file.  But you can slightly tighten up your code by consolidating your `if` statements.  You should probably check for the existence of `'foo'` before iterating over all of the tuples.

```
with open('connection_details.txt', 'r') as f:
    c.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION')
    # for each line in ~16k lines
    for line in f:
        # for each row returned from sql query
        if 'foo' in line:
            for tup in tuples:
                if tup[0] in line and tup[1] in line:
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `for` loops, you could use `itertools` and you could turn your `if` statements into a single one like so:

```
import itertools

for line, tuple in itertools.product(f, tuples):
    if tuple[0] in line and tuple[1] in line and 'foo' in line:
```